# Netbeans append error

Tags: java

I'm getting errors on all my `.append()` calls on my `textArea`. Why am I getting this problem?

```
private void outputComputer(Computer computer) {
        textArea.append("Laptop: " + computer.getLaptop());
        textArea.append("Processor: ");
        textArea.append(computer.getProcessor());
        textArea.append("Graphics Card: ");
        textArea.append(computer.getGraphicsCard());
        textArea.append("Ram: ");
        textArea.append(computer.getRam());
        textArea.append("Hard Drive: ");
        textArea.append(computer.getHardDrive());
        textArea.append("Operating System: ");
        textArea.append(computer.getOperatingSystem());
        textArea.append("Monitor Size: ");
        textArea.append(computer.getMonitorSize());

    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What error and why are you tagging this as javascript? You need to provide more details.

Comment: cannot find symbol symbol: method append(String) location: variable textArea of type Object

Comment: You need to update your question with the error and the definition of `textArea`. What is it and where is it defined?

Comment: Posted an answer. But couldn't pass without saying... In your future questions, in order to get more attention and quality answers, consider providing more information about what happens, rather then saying "I am getting errors".

Comment: @HarpreetSunner should you be declaring `textArea` as a `JTextArea` and not an `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only code you have, then all I can say is that you don't have your `textArea` defined anywhere. You have to create a value and fill it with something before calling its attributes. Long story short, you cannot get an "undefined" or "null" value's something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

Changing "append" to "setText" worked for me.

```
    private void outputComputer(Computer computer) {

    textArea.setText("Laptop: " + computer.getLaptop());
    textArea.setText("Processor: ");
    textArea.setText(computer.getProcessor());
    textArea.setText("Graphics Card: ");
    textArea.setText(computer.getGraphicsCard());
    textArea.setText("Ram: ");
    textArea.setText(computer.getRam());
    textArea.setText("Hard Drive: ");
    textArea.setText(computer.getHardDrive());
    textArea.setText("Operating System: ");
    textArea.setText(computer.getOperatingSystem());
    textArea.setText("Monitor Size: ");
    textArea.setText(computer.getMonitorSize());

}
```